# Sequelize sync model

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have used [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/) for building my backend service. Now I need to make an "alter" to some table and "create" also some table. While I was in development I set the options to sequelize `.sync({force: true})` that it drop all table and recreate it by models. Now I don't want this because I erase all data, anyone know how can I make this?

So make an alter table if model is different and don't truncate data or create table if not exist or maybe drop table if model was deleted.

Thanks.

Comment: just using .sync() isn't doing what you want?

Comment: It works to create new table only, but if table exists and I make an update to model it doesn't sync. I think to use `migrations` for that... @AliBARIN

Comment: `sequelize-cli` has `createTable`, `changeColumn` etc  functions